# Creating an Associative Array using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to create an `associative array` using `JQuery`. I would like it to be filled with the values of the checkboxes a user has selected from the `UI`.

I was creating the array like this at first:

```
$contentArray = [];
$('.content-filter :checked').each(function(){
    $contentArray.push(this.value);
})
```

but the problem with this is that when I pass it to a `php` script via `Ajax` it was making it very difficult to get values from it. I'd rather be able to get the values from the array based on the key associated with it.

So I decided to modify my code to this:

```
$contentArray = new Array(); //Hold checked "content" filters
//Content Filter - cycle through each filter and add value of checked ones to array
$('.content-filter :checked').each(function(){
    $contentArray[this.value] = this.value;
})
```

however now when I perform `console.log` I am being told the contents of my array contains nothing.

Can anyone advise me on how to fix this issue and show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You want a JavaSript [*object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays. It has Arrays and it has Objects, and arrays happen to be objects.

Comment: I don't understand. How can mapping value to value (i.e. `$contentArray[this.value] = this.value;`) be of any use whatsoever? You'd need to know the key to look up the value. But the value of the key would have to be the actual value that's stored against it, making a lookup completely pointless.

Comment: @spender, in this instance it makes the most sense for me to do it like this. I am trying to pass all of the filters checked by a user to a php script that will cycle through an array holding these filters and construct an sql statement accordingly.

Comment: @Javacadabra Then why not an array of the checked values, or an object with the values as keys and their states as boolean elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter is wrong - you need to remove the space before `:checked`, otherwise it will look for an element *inside* the checkbox which is checked, which obviously doesn't exist:

```js
$contentArray = new Array(); //Hold checked "content" filters
//Content Filter - cycle through each filter and add value of checked ones to array
$('.content-filter:checked').each(function(){
    $contentArray[this.value] = this.value;
})

console.log($contentArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="2" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="5" />
```

However, as mentioned, this just creates a fragmented array. If you want truly associative keys, you should create an object (tho I don't see this being easier to process in php):

```js
$contentObject = {}; //Hold checked "content" filters
//Content Filter - cycle through each filter and add value of checked ones to array
$('.content-filter:checked').each(function(){
    $contentObject[this.value] = this.value;
})

console.log($contentObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="2" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="3" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="content-filter" value="5" />
```